# How to disable/turn off the logging feature from Storm

Tags: java, log4j, apache-storm

I want to turn off the logging feature offered by default when we run from local cluster.
Currently its logging so many information on the console.

Below is the example of log:

```
261 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.task  - Shut down task Getting-Started-Toplogie-1-1376388324:2
2261 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.task  - Shutting down task Getting-Started-Toplogie-1-1376388324:1
2262 [Thread-24] INFO  backtype.storm.util  - Async loop interrupted!
2276 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.task  - Shut down task Getting-Started-Toplogie-1-1376388324:1
2278 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker  - Terminating zmq context
2279 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker  - Disconnecting from storm cluster state context
2279 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker  - Waiting for heartbeat thread to die
2279 [Thread-27] INFO  backtype.storm.util  - Async loop interrupted!
2308 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.testing  - Shutting down in process zookeeper
2309 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.testing  - Done shutting down in process zookeeper
2309 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.testing  - Deleting temporary path /tmp/255fe7c8-1407-4f43-8771-2217905232ab
```

After going through many docs, I ended up with the below code, I am able to turn off the logging from within class.

```
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TopologyMain.class);

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, AlreadyAliveException, InvalidTopologyException {        
      logger.setLevel((Level) Level.FATAL);
      logger.debug("Here is some DEBUG");
      logger.info("Here is some INFO");
      logger.warn("Here is some WARN");
      logger.error("Here is some ERROR");
      logger.fatal("Here is some FATAL");
 }
}
```

Output (correct) : `0    [main] FATAL TopologyMain  - Here is some FATAL`

But I require to change the logging configure of storm/zookeper,etc..

Could anyone please help on this?

---

**Update**: The following is the code I tried, but it does not work. I tried with version 0.7.1, 0.8.2 & 0.9.0-wip*

```
        //Configuration
        Config conf = new Config();
        conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_DEBUG, false);  //Tried this alone
        conf.setDebug(false);  //Tried this alone & tried both together as well.. No change :-(
```

Comment: What to you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: I mean still I am getting the same log output as I've mentioned `example of log`

Comment: How did you solve this?  It looks like you updated your question to express the inability to implement the accepted answer.

Comment: I think he is saying that the logs still contains tons of INFO level messages.  That is the actual problem.  Debug is not the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Storm is really chatty and tells a lot of information but if you want to silence it, you can set [Config.TOPOLOGY_DEBUG](http://nathanmarz.github.io/storm/doc/backtype/storm/Config.html#TOPOLOGY_DEBUG) to false.

When you set Config.TOPOLOGY_DEBUG to true, you are telling Storm to log a message every time a tuple is emitted from any spout or bolt.

Comment: I found that storm includes a log4j.properties in classpath: is there a way to exclude it and overwrite it with my own? I tried different things with maven plugins, but no luck.

Comment: To do what is suggested here, you can use `Config::setDebug(false)`

Answer (score 2):

Add below code in log4j.xml.It will just print your intended logs and console outputs :-

```
<logger name="org.apache.zookeeper">
        <level value="warn"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="backtype.storm">
        <level value="warn"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.netflix">
        <level value="warn"/>
    </logger>
```

And use Logger.getLogger(Class) in your classes.

Comment: Ideally It should work.. please check whether your log4j configuration is proper or not?

Comment: Works now. Turns out that I had to put it in my `logback.xml` file. Besides, `backtype.storm` is outdated. So used these: ` <logger name="org.apache.storm" level="OFF"/>
 <logger name="org.apache.zookeeper" level="OFF"/>`

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (storm version 0.9.0.1):

```
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
builder.setSpout(..);
builder.setBolt(..);
:

Config conf = new Config();
conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_DEBUG, false);

LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
cluster.submitTopology("topologyName", conf, builder.createTopology());
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this question when attempting to evaluate Storm using a local testing environment.  I created a project depending on `storm-core` version `1.1.0`, which is the latest stable release at the time of this writing, so I don't know if this applies for anyone else.

Inspecting the Maven dependencies, and expanding the contents of the `storm-core-1.1.0.jar` revealed that the configuration file for the library's log4j logging dependency was called `log4j2.xml`.  With the realization that the logging mechanism was log4j *2* , I consulted the documentation here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/index.html I created a new `log4j2.xml` file under `src/main/resources` (my project is Maven-configured, so this is at the classpath root).  I started by copying the contents of the existing file, and changing the log levels for the specified loggers  to "OFF":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration monitorInterval="60">
      <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
          <PatternLayout pattern="%-4r [%t] %-5p %c{1.} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
      </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
       <Logger name="org.apache.zookeeper" level="OFF"/>
         <Root level="OFF">
           <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
         </Root>
    </Loggers>
</configuration>
```

Running a "hello world" example, *regardless of the setting of `conf.debug()`* indicates that - since there is now no mechanism by which logging should be possible at all - the logs (most usefully System.out) are now dead silent, except for the invocations of `System.out.println()` I placed in my test spouts / bolts. This is exactly what I wanted!  Hopefully this helps someone other than me!

Comment: I think it should be the accepted answer. Really, setting `log4j2` is the correct way... Turning off the log completely is not desirable. Log4j2 has finer control on this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice documentation on setting up the log level dynamically. It can be done through the UI as well as using the CLI. The later looks better to me. Once you start the topology you can simply use the following command (from inside Storm's installation directory):

```
    ./bin/storm set_log_level [topology name] -l [logger name]=[LEVEL]:[TIMEOUT]
```

For more details please check [this link](http://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/dynamic-log-level-settings.html)

Answer (score 0):

Creat a file "log4j2.xml" in src/main/resources (Maven project) works for me!

```
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="org.apache.storm" level="OFF"/>
    <Logger name="org.apache.zookeeper" level="OFF"/>
    <Root level="OFF">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```