# How to clean workers-artifacts and storm-logs on ec2 server for apache storm

Tags: java, logging, amazon-ec2, apache-storm

I have storm running on a ubuntu server. The logs and snapshots are stored in the `storm-logs/workers-artifacts` directory.
This takes a lot of space and I want to get rid of this data. Most of these data are older and I need ways to manage or remove them automatically.

These are the ways I am looking for

- Log rotation and deletion of logs, but I am not sure if it will remove the complete artifact repository or just the logs of topology.
- worker.xml of log4j2 doesn't seem to be working well.
- We have the option of using cron-job and through bash shell tracking the last modified date.
- How to do this at `topology` level?

Update:
This is my `worker.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->

<configuration monitorInterval="60">
<properties>
    <property name="pattern">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %c{1.} [%p] %msg%n</property>
    <property name="patternNoTime">%msg%n</property>
    <property name="patternMetrics">%d %-8r %m%n</property>
</properties>
<appenders>
    <RollingFile name="A1"
        fileName="${sys:workers.artifacts}/${sys:storm.id}/${sys:worker.port}/${sys:logfile.name}"
        filePattern="${sys:workers.artifacts}/${sys:storm.id}/${sys:worker.port}/${sys:logfile.name}.%i.gz">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>${pattern}</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 * * * ?"/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB"/> <!-- Or every 100 MB -->
        </Policies>
<!--        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="9"/>-->
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
            <Delete basePath="${sys:workers.artifacts}/${sys:storm.id}" maxDepth="10">
                <IfLastModified age="3d" >
                    <IfAny>
                        <IfAccumulatedFileSize exceeds="5 GB" />
                        <IfAccumulatedFileCount exceeds="15" />
                    </IfAny>
                </IfLastModified>
            </Delete>
        </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>
    <RollingFile name="STDOUT"
        fileName="${sys:workers.artifacts}/${sys:storm.id}/${sys:worker.port}/${sys:logfile.name}.out"
        filePattern="${sys:workers.artifacts}/${sys:storm.id}/${sys:worker.port}/${sys:logfile.name}.out.%i.gz">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>${patternNoTime}</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB"/> <!-- Or every 100 MB -->
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="4"/>
    </RollingFile>
    <RollingFile name="STDERR"
        fileName="${sys:workers.artifacts}/${sys:storm.id}/${sys:worker.port}/${sys:logfile.name}.err"
        filePattern="${sys:workers.artifacts}/${sys:storm.id}/${sys:worker.port}/${sys:logfile.name}.err.%i.gz">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>${patternNoTime}</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB"/> <!-- Or every 100 MB -->
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="4"/>
    </RollingFile>
    <RollingFile name="METRICS"
        fileName="${sys:workers.artifacts}/${sys:storm.id}/${sys:worker.port}/${sys:logfile.name}.metrics"
        filePattern="${sys:workers.artifacts}/${sys:storm.id}/${sys:worker.port}/${sys:logfile.name}.metrics.%i.gz">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>${patternMetrics}</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="2 MB"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="9"/>
    </RollingFile>
    <Syslog name="syslog" format="RFC5424" charset="UTF-8" host="localhost" port="514"
        protocol="UDP" appName="[${sys:storm.id}:${sys:worker.port}]" mdcId="mdc" includeMDC="true"
        facility="LOCAL5" enterpriseNumber="18060" newLine="true" exceptionPattern="%rEx{full}"
        messageId="[${sys:user.name}:${sys:logging.sensitivity}]" id="storm" immediateFail="true" immediateFlush="true"/>
</appenders>
<loggers>
    <root level="info"> <!-- We log everything -->
        <appender-ref ref="A1"/>
        <appender-ref ref="syslog"/>
    </root>
    <Logger name="org.apache.storm.metric.LoggingMetricsConsumer" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="METRICS"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="STDERR" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDERR"/>
        <appender-ref ref="syslog"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="STDOUT" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="syslog"/>
    </Logger>
</loggers>
</configuration>
```

Comment: For me, modiying the `worker.xml`-file works if running in distributed multi-node setup.
Are you really sure that its modification is not helpful? You can set there log-rotation, file size limits, and so on...

Comment: @moosehead42, I have added my worker.xml, can you please look into this, and tell me if there is any error.

Comment: 1. **Disable debugging**, this reduces logging massively.
2. For further reduction and **log4j-Settings**, see **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206821/how-to-disable-turn-off-the-logging-feature-from-storm)**